# ShakeGesture library WP7 - Shake count

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, shake

i've being reading about your ShakeGesture library and it's really good!
But i was wondering if there is a way for use this library for count the numbers of a shake.
For example, i want to have an app where the user needs to shake the phone 30 times. If the user shakes it 10 times, something will happen. If 20 times, other thing will happen.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I sense possible repetitive stress disorder lawsuits in the works.

Comment: Sorry, not "your", just "the" ShakeGesture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ShakeGesture](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/Recipe_Shake_Gesture_Library) library doesn't include a way of reporting how many times a device was moved as part of a shake.

However, it does allow you to customize the `MinimumRequiredMovesForShake`. You could try creating multiple instances of the listener, each configured to listen for a different number of moves and then handle the events differently.

Comment: Thanks man, that's a nice approach. I'll see if that will work. Cheers